# How do I reassign element IDs on a sortable list using KendoUI and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm working on a sortable list that utilises the KendoUI jQuery library.  I have a basic list that you can reorder and I'd like to reassign the ids of the list items once they have been moved.  For example, if you move a list item with an id of "plot3" to the top of the list, I'd like to change that id to "plot1" and the original "plot1" to "plot3" and so forth.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<ul id="plot__points">
    <li class="sortable" id="plot1">Location #1</li>
    <li class="sortable" id="plot2">Location #2</li>
    <li class="sortable" id="plot3">Location #3</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the script that controls the basic functionality of the sortable list.  This is kendoUI code out of the box.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#plot__points").kendoSortable({
            hint:function(element) {
                return element.clone().addClass("hint"); 
             }, placeholder:function(element) {
                 return element.clone().addClass("placeholder").text("drop here");
                  }, cursorOffset: {
                      top: -10,
                      left: -230
      }});
    })
</script>
```

Is this something that can easily be done using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the ids using a `for` loop. That is, if the DOM elements are reordered too (which I think are). This way you'll always have your ids in ascending order.

```
$("#plot__points > li").each(function(index, item){
    $(this).attr("id", "plot" + (index + 1));
})
```

Edit: As @ezanker said, put the above code into kendoSortable. See his [Dojo here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/unEgEv).

Comment: I would put your code in the change event of the kendoSortable:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/unEgEv

Comment: @ezanker Thanks for that and the Dojo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code based on the examples given by @Adriani6 and @ezanker

```
@(Html.Kendo().Sortable()
    .For("#plot__points")
    .Cursor("url('" + Url.Content("~/content/web/sortable/grabbing.cur") + "'), default")
    .CursorOffset(offset => offset.Left(-230).Top(-10))
    .HintHandler("hint")
    .Disabled(".disabled")
    .Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
    .PlaceholderHandler("placeholder")
)

<script>
    function onChange(e) {
        $("#plot__points > li").each(function (index, item) {
            $(this).prop("id", "plot" + (index + 1));
        });
    }
</script>
```